# View and change every Xminutes specific pictures in Raspberry PI

Tags: pi-2, script, software-recommendation

I want to view and change specific pictures in raspberry pi. As example I have a picture1.jpg and I want to view It for 3minutes, and I have picture2.jpg that I want to view for 5minutes. Is there any software,script that can do that?

Comment: You could do it in a browser with a little javascript, You could write a shell script. You may also want to check out this instructable http://www.instructables.com/id/Easy-Raspberry-Pi-Based-ScreensaverSlideshow-for-E/ This search will turn up several other options https://www.google.com/search?q=slide+softeare+raspberry+pi&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8. You can also try searching for raspberry pi digital picture frame

Answer (score 3):

[`xloadimage`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xloadimage) `-fullscreen -delay 180 picture1.jpg -delay 300 picture2.jpg`

I assumed you want pictures to be shown fullscreen. Remove the corresponding option if this is not the case.